# How to put the green diamond back in it's original position in AutoCAD 2018

Tags: cad, autocad

[image]

How would I go about resetting the position of the green diamond which acts as an anchor point for these text objects? 
The idea is to be able to move the text box around with the green diamond in it's original position where it moves around with the text box, as it is by default.